# OpenTextFile on a remote computer

Tags: vbscript, path, unc

I'm trying to read remote text files using this code:

```
function defdate(ipaddress)
  deffilePath = chr(34) & "\\" & ipaddress & "\c$\" & deffileName & chr(34)
  wscript.echo deffilePath
  set deffile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(deffilePath)
  do while not deffile.endofstream
    s=deffile.readline    
    wscript.echo s
  loop
deffile.close
end function
```

My deffilePath below expands into strings like this:

`"\\10.211.19.207\c$\Program Files\Common Files\Symantec Shared\VirusDefs\definfo.dat"`

However, I get "Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Bad file name or number".
What could be the problem?

Comment: Is c$ not the problem?

Comment: No, the problem is the missing backslash. "c$" is the name of the hidden share that Windows creates by default for the "c:" drive.

Comment: Andy, the backslash isn't missing -- that's a rendering problem.

Comment: I know that now Roger, I commented before you fixed that.
*waves*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (read: "must not") enclose your path in quotes.

```
deffilePath = "\\" & ipaddress & "\c$\" & deffileName
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to include the quotes -- the CHR(34) -- when using the command-line, or for similar APIs. If a method takes just a filename, leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "chr(34)" at the beginning and the end. When typing a path in the Windows run menu you need those quotes, but when passing a path to a function call like this you don't want them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the chr(34) at the end?

Comment: Whoever -1 me, add it back.  I was right, I just missed the chr(34) at the beginning should be removed as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need two backslashes at the start of an UNC pathname. Try adding another one!

My guess would be that it works with "\\10.211.19.207\c$\Program Files\Common Files\Symantec Shared\VirusDefs\definfo.dat".

Comment: Well spotted, but I just missed that when I copied the text.  I do have two backslashes

Comment: OK, then I'm afraid I don't know what the problem is. Good luck anyway! :)